Gateway Timeout - The gateway did not receive a timely response from the upstream server or application
I was able to run other Django apps using these same settings but when I installed Django CMS these settings no longer worked. Yes, the other app is running on Python 3.7 and I'm using 3.8 for Django CMS. Below is the error log and other settings. Please any help would be greatly appreciated.
Error log:
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/siteuser/public_html/core/wsgi.py", line 12, in
from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'django'
mod_wsgi (pid=13800): Failed to exec Python script file '/home/siteuser/public_html/core/wsgi.py'.
mod_wsgi (pid=13800): Exception occurred processing WSGI script '/home/siteuser/public_html/core/wsgi.py'.
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/siteuser/public_html/core/wsgi.py", line 12, in
from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'django'
mod_wsgi (pid=13800): Failed to exec Python script file '/home/siteuser/public_html/core/wsgi.py'.
mod_wsgi (pid=13800): Exception occurred processing WSGI script '/home/siteuser/public_html/core/wsgi.py'.
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/siteuser/public_html/core/wsgi.py", line 12, in
from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'django'
Timeout when reading response headers from daemon process 'siteuser.net': /home/siteuser/public_html/core/wsgi.py
Timeout when reading response headers from daemon process 'siteuser.net': /home/siteuser/public_html/core/wsgi.py
Timeout when reading response headers from daemon process 'siteuser.net': /home/siteuser/public_html/core/wsgi.py, referer: https://siteuser.net/
Timeout when reading response headers from daemon process 'siteuser.net': /home/siteuser/public_html/core/wsgi.py

wsgi.py
import os
from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
sys.path.append('/home/siteuser/public_html/')
sys.path.append('/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages')
os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'core.settings')
application = get_wsgi_application()

.conf
WSGIDaemonProcess siteuser.net python-home=/home/siteuser/public_html/venv
WSGIProcessGroup siteuser.net
WSGIScriptAlias / /home/siteuser/public_html/core/wsgi.py

<Directory "/home/siteuser/public_html/core">
    <Files wsgi.py>
        Require all granted
    </Files>
</Directory>


Eventually I found a solution. It seems to be a bug with the sqlite database as I saw a database error when I directed all debug information to a log file. The system cannot query the database correctly. Probably because of currupted data. I switched entirely to mysql and after migration, the site was available.
